# Query with EF 5, Associations VS Linq join

Tags: linq, entity-framework, join, ef-code-first, associations

I am interested in what way is the 'Best Practice' for making queries with EF 5.

For example let's have 2 Tables: Movie and Genre that have many-to-many relationship so there is a third table GenreMovie with MovieId and GenreId as FKs.

It means that one genre have several movies but also one movie can be mix of genres.

And on client side there are 2 grids, genre list on the left and movie list on right.

For selected genre, movie list will not only show movies from that genre but all the movie, where those that belong to this genre will be check.

This select can be accomplished on 2 way, that have the same result.

int genreId = 1; (genre with id = 1 is selected)

1. using EF Associations

   ```
   var q = db.Movies
         .Select(m => new
         {
             MovieId = m.MovieId,
             Title = m.Title,
             Selected = m.GenreMovies.Where(gm => gm.GenreId == genreId).Count() > 0,
         });
   ```
2. using Linq join

   ```
   var q = from m in db.Movies
            join gm in db.GenreMovies.Where(gm => gm.GenreId == genreId) on m.MovieId equals gm.MovieId into gms
            from gm in gms.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
            {
                MovieId = m.MovieId,
                Title = m.Title,
                Selected = gm != null
            };
   ```

Obviously first way has less code and looks simpler.

But is it really better way, and best practice?

Since I heard that EF associations doesn't always makes best conversion to SQL queries regarding optimisation.

I have also looked into Sql Profiler to see the resulting query for both ways.
And I saw the following:(1. way seems to make query with more lines, but I am not sure is it less efficient or not) ???

I tried to made some test with several hundreds thousands record but still both ways were just too fast to see any difference.

1.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project2].[MovieId] AS [MovieId], 
[Project2].[Title] AS [Title], 
CASE WHEN ([Project2].[C1] > 0) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ([Project2].[C2] > 0)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
[Project1].[MovieId] AS [MovieId], 
[Project1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
(SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[GenreMovie] AS [Extent3]
    WHERE ([Project1].[MovieId] = [Extent3].[MovieId]) AND ([Extent3].[GenreId] = @p__linq__0)) AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [c].[MovieId] AS [MovieId], 
    [c].[Title] AS [Title], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[GenreMovie] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([c].[MovieId] = [Extent2].[MovieId]) AND ([Extent2].[GenreId] = @p__linq__0)) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Movie] AS [c]
)  AS [Project1])     
AS [Project2]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=1
```

2.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Limit1].[MovieId] AS [MovieId], 
[Limit1].[Title] AS [Title], 
CASE WHEN ([Limit1].[GenreMovieId] IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ([Limit1].[GenreMovieId] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1000) 
[Extent1].[MovieId] AS [MovieId], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent2].[GenreMovieId] AS [GenreMovieId]
FROM  [dbo].[Movie] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[GenreMovie] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[GenreId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[MovieId] = [Extent2].[MovieId]))  
AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
var q = db.Movies
      .Select(m => new
      {
          MovieId = m.MovieId,
          Title = m.Title,
          Selected = m.GenreMovies.Any(gm => gm.GenreId == genreId),
      });
```

only for simplicity reasons.

Comment: Plus for the simplification.